# How to create an overlay window in Java?

Tags: java, cocoa, swing, macos, overlay

I'm trying to create a HUD style display for a foreign application.

To do this, I'd need to make a transparent overlay window, that would be placed on top
of the window of the foreign application. The overlay window should allow me to place
widgets and draw text on it. Events should get forwarded to the underlying window,
if they happen on the transparent area (and otherwise allow the widgets to work as
expected).

I'm doing this on OSX with Java. I'd hope to do this with pure Java with portability to
other platforms, but if not possible, I'd be fine with solutions that would just allow
me to do this on OSX through Cocoa (Rococoa) or Carbon.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) show one way this can be accomplished. Here's another approach that uses RGBA (red, green, blue, alpha) values for the background colour:

```java
public class Overlay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Transparent Window");
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        // Without this, the window is draggable from any non transparent
        // point, including points  inside textboxes.
        frame.getRootPane().putClientProperty("apple.awt.draggableWindowBackground", false);

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JTextField("text field north"), java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JTextField("text field south"), java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: You know if this also works for Buttons? I.e. if I wan't some sort of semi-transparent Button on top of another application, where the event isn't forwarded to the underlying application but to the button so I can press it?