# What do I do if I want to draw some text on other program?

Tags: c#, dll-injection

I want to write a helper program to display some text on the other program. e.g.: I can display my guess on tiles in minesweeper in windows.

update 0906: I don't need inject a program, I can just **check pixels** on screen and **show some text** on ***screen***. Is there some idea?

How can I do this?

Comment: This isn't an easy task, as far as I know you would have to inject the process. Also Minesweeper probably doesn't use OpenGL.

Comment: @AdamS how about directX? C# code something?

Comment: Why don't you write a program that takes a image of minesweeper, and your own program writes the texts over the image.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato I want to display it real time. I don't know if my image can keep minesweeper out?

Comment: Well, I've seen what you want done in java before but that was a runescape macro. I don't know how to help you but I'm interested in seeing the responses you get.

Comment: This might be of interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768062/how-to-create-an-overlay-window-in-java

Comment: @JohnRiselvato yeah, that gives me some inspire

Comment: @MoreFreeze: what you want to do is completely outside the scope of OpenGL. And injecting a DLL into the other process is the only way to go, because processes are protected from each other by the OS. So you need some hook to do what you want from the inside.

Comment: I might be mistaken but in early days one could paint anywhere on the screen in Windows. So the idea is that the screen is not protected, it does not belong to any specific process. Just choose Your location right and start setting pixels...