# How to write small text that stays on top of other windows on java?

Tags: java, swing, awt, overlay, ping

I've made a small program that pings a certain IP each second. From the ping response, I get the time=XXms parameter.

I would like to display this number maybe on the top left corner of my screen and make it stay on top of other windows(like an overlay).

Anyone know how I could go about doing this?

Thank you for the attention!

Comment: You can try something like in the linked post, but please note that you'll be unable to click things directly under your display. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768062/how-to-create-an-overlay-window-in-java

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be exactly what I needed, now I just need to figure out how to display the ping time!